# Recursive call outcome

Tags: java, recursion

I'm new to java and I was studying some articles about Recursion when I stumbled upon this little program which I don't understand.

```
static void  print(int i) {

    if ( i > 1) {
       System.out.print("Y");
       print(i-1);
    }

    for (int t = 0; t < i ; t++)
       System.out.print(i); // i not t
    }
```

When I do `print(4)` the outcome is `YYY1223334444` but why isn't it `YYY1`? I don't get that part.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger? (Hint: after the `if` block has completed, what do you think will happen?)

Comment: Oeh thats a good one, I'll try it out immediately, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer provided by Gerald Mücke is the best approach: roll out the code and see in what order the methods are actually called. What is important to know is that the recursive `print(i-1)` call is **blocking**. It will wait until its invocation has returned before it continues onto the the next statement, which is the for loop. This means that by the time you get to the call where the `i` argument is 1, you are 4 calls deep: print(4) -> print(3) -> print(2) -> print(1). This is why people speak of a "call stack" and why you get a stack trace if you output an exception. Oh, and why you get the stackoverflow error that this very site is called after if your call stack goes so deep (for example, recursion without an end condition) that it exceeds a certain value.

While Gerald typed his answer I was making a visual representation that might help you undestand better. The colored blocks are method invocations, with nesting showing how they sit on top one another in the call stack, and arrows for the program's statement flow.
[image: recursive program flow & call stack]

Comment: couldn't ask for a more proper answer than this! thank you.

Comment: What did you use to create this fancy diagram?

Comment: @Gala I used draw.io, which you can just use in the browser and is free. It's by jGraph. As far as diagramming software goes this one seems to put up the least resistance to my efforts to make something :D

Comment: A+ for the drawing. @G_H

Answer (score 5):

Let's roll out the ifs, recursion and the loop. What the system does its:

```
print(i=4) {
  System.out.print("Y")          -> Y
  print(i=3) {
    System.out.print("Y")        -> YY
    print(i=2){
      System.out.print("Y")        -> YYY
      print(i=1){
        //skip if and print 1x i=1
        System.out.print(1)        -> YYY1
      }
      //print 2x i=2 
      System.out.print(2)        -> YYY12
      System.out.print(2)        -> YYY122
    }
    //print 3x i=3
    System.out.print(3)        -> YYY1223
    System.out.print(3)        -> YYY12233
    System.out.print(3)        -> YYY122333
  }
  //print 4x i=4
  System.out.print(4)        -> YYY1223334
  System.out.print(4)        -> YYY12233344
  System.out.print(4)        -> YYY122333444
  System.out.print(4)        -> YYY1223334444
}
```

The code deos not return after the if but execute the for loop.

If you're new to Java, make yourself familiar with a debugger, which allows a step-by-step execution and value introspection and is part of every Java IDE

Comment: Thanks, but one little question. After the `if` the code executes the `for`loop, but isn't `i`at that moment 1, how does it become 2?

Comment: @YoussefSakuragi By returning to the invocation of the method from which it was called, where `i` is 2.  A fundamental concept in recursion is that the multiple calls are stacked up until you get back to them.

Comment: the `i-1` does not change the value of `i`, instead it creates a new value, which is passed to the next invocation. But once the method returns, the value of the original `i` is valid again,

Comment: @YoussefSakuragi Look up "call by value" and "call by reference", then learn how Java does things. The `i-1` is evaluated and that value is passed to the method call as argument.